# Incorrect Status Code returned on MVC AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes

I'm submitting a standard [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: myUrl
    success: function(data) {
        $("#replace").html(data)
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.warn(data);
    }
});
```

Or the same thing by attaching the handler to the [ajax promise](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) callbacks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: myUrl
})
.done(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(data, status) {
    console.warn(status);
});
```

In both cases, or when using [`$.ajaxError()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/), the error/fail function is called when a HTTP status error is returned.

---

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I'm trying to return the proper **HTTP Status Code**, both for semantic reasons and to be caught by the right client side handler.

**Attempt #1** - As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702126/1366033) I've tried to return a [`HttpStatusCodeResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult) like this:

```cs
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, accessResult.AccessDeniedMessage);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
       base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Attempt #2** - Alternatively, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085769/1366033), I've tried returning a `JsonResult` and also setting the [`Response.StatusCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpResponse.StatusCode)

```cs
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
{
    Data = new { Error = "Unauthorized User" },
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
```

In both cases, the response still comes back as **200 OK**

[image: AJAX Status Code Screenshot]

#### Questions:

- Am I correct about the semantics that I should be returning an AJAX response with a Unauthorized Status Code?
- Is there somewhere else to set this value that I need to do also?
- Is there some server level setting to allow non-200 status codes to be returned?

---

This question on [Always success on ajax post with HttpResponseMessage 401](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20662608/1366033) seems to be running into the same error, but doesn't propose a server side solution, instead just allowing the OK error status code and scraping the response to determine if an error occurred.

Comment: Not quite sure why this isn't working as expected, but I do notice that in your picture the Response Headers has a `X-Responded-JSON` which actually contains your response data as JSON. Maybe try to clear the response first: `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();`

Comment: @TheMuffinMan, Yeah - I saw that too - I think there are definitely ways to stuff data somewhere into the response and to be able to react appropriately on the client. Lots of people will add `Success` to their returned `Data` object, but it's still bothering me from a semantic point of view that the request is unauthorized and still being returned with a `200` status when I've manually specified something else

Comment: In the first example where you check if type of current request `isajaxrequest` there could you change your code to `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();` and try?probably you are not setting the response.

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar, added a call to `Response.End()` on each attempt and in both cases the return status was still 200

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Always success on ajax post with HttpResponseMessage 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662608/always-success-on-ajax-post-with-httpresponsemessage-401)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending issue was indeed the same as in [Always success on ajax post with HttpResponseMessage 401](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20662608/1366033). The response was returned successfully, but trapped a redirect to a form login

```
X-Responded-JSON: {"status": 401, "headers": {"location":"http:\/\/localhost:50004\/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FClient"}}
```

Although that question doesn't seem to suggest a server side solution, instead simply relying on a parsing the error state on the client. **Brock Allen** suggests a server side fix in his post on [Using cookie authentication middleware with Web API and 401 response codes](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/using-cookie-authentication-middleware-with-web-api-and-401-response-codes/):

> Normally when using cookie authentication middleware, when the server (MVC or WebForms) issues a 401, then the response is converted to a 302 redirect to the login page (as configured by the LoginPath on the [**CookieAuthenticationOptions**](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/)). But when an Ajax call is made and the response is a 401, it would not make sense to return a 302 redirect to the login page. Instead you’d just expect the 401 response to be returned. Unfortunately this is not the behavior we get with the cookie middleware — the response is changed to a 200 status code with a JSON response body with a message:
>
> ```js
> {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
> ```
>
> I’m not sure what the requirement was for this feature. To alter it, you must take over control of the behavior when there is a 401 unauthorized response by configuring a CookieAuthenticationProvider on the cookie authentication middleware:
>
> ```
> app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
> {
>    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
>    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
>    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
>    {
>       OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
>       {
>          if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
>          {
>             ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
>          }
>      }
>    }
> });
> ```
>
> Notice it handles the OnApplyRedirect event. When the call is not an Ajax call, we redirect. Otherwise, we do nothing which allows the 401 to be returned to the caller.
>
> The check for IsAjaxRequest is simply copied from a [**helper**](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/v3.1.0/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/Provider/DefaultBehavior.cs#L36) in the katana project:
>
> ```
> private static bool IsAjaxRequest(IOwinRequest request)
> {
>    IReadableStringCollection query = request.Query;
>    if ((query != null) && (query["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"))
>    {
>       return true;
>    }
>    IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
>    return ((headers != null) && (headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
> }
> ```